# Can we apply filter/sort or fetch records based on value of relationship as To Many in coredata?

Tags: core-data

Can we apply filter/sort or fetch records based on the value of relationship in multiple/multilevel entities as to Many in core data?

Comment: If you can give us some more context on what you are trying to solve. What exact data are you using to solve this.

Comment: @SachinVas

Say I have three tables named “tbl1”,“tbl2” and “tbl3”
now the relationship is as
tbl1 to tbl2 as one to one and tbl2 to tbl3 as one to many.

Now I want to fetch all records of tbl1 based on some condition equality of tbl3’s column(tbl3 will have to many relation with tbl2).

Comment: You can run a subquery using to fetch such kind of data, see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_sub_queries.htm

Comment: Doing same, but no succeess yet. Anyway thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: What is want is possible in core data & just need to sharpen my predates. Correct?

Comment: Yeah, you need to improve the predicates to fetch the correct set of data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but you have to use the ANY or ALL keyword for a to-many relationship.  There are a also a few issues to look out for.

If you use this predicate in a `NSFetchedResultsController` then changes to the relationship will not trigger changes for the fetchedResultsController.  For example if you had a fetchedResultsController to select all rock songs with the predicate 
`[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY musicCollection.genre == %@", @"Rock"]` the fetchedResultsController will trigger if you set the musicCollection for song, but wouldn't if you change the genre of a musicCollection.

The second issue is that if you are are selecting based on multiple criteria of the relationship property then you should use `SUBQUERY`. Otherwise it will result in multiple faulting for each predicate.